# How to decode transaction input data using `ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder`

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, ethers.js, etherscan

I'm fetching transaction data using Etherscan API. This is the example result I'm getting:

```
{
  blockNumber: '7409930',
  timeStamp: '1639151980',
  hash: '...',
  nonce: '4124',
  ...
  input: '0x9d90e4c8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000093238bb66b5d15b4152c5db574e3397ff1b1a450',
  contractAddress: '',
  cumulativeGasUsed: '403775',
  gasUsed: '1162315',
  confirmations: '191308'
}
```

I now need to figure out the event type (contract method, e.g. `TransferOwnership`, `stakeTokens`,...) for this transaction. This data is stored in `input` property of this object.

I managed to accomplish this using `abi-decoder` library, but I want to accomplish the same thing using ethers's utility method (whichever).

My current implementation:

```
const abiDecoder = require("abi-decoder");
abiDecoder.addABI(contractAbi);
// "item" is transaction data, input property is encoded stuff from which I want to get the contract method used by this transaction
const decodedInput = abiDecoder.decodeMethod(item.input);

// contract method
console.log(decodedInput.name);
```

I was reading through ether's documentation (https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/abi/coder/), but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

you can try what is recommended in this: https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/423 . but if you are interacting with BSC, this is not possible due to the error input data too big causing Error in Big Number `Number can only safely store up to 53 bits`